# Configuring ActiveMQ Webconsole to redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: jetty, activemq-classic, http-redirect

I am using ActiveMQ Version 5.7.0 with Jetty on a RHEL 7 VM.
I have already enabled the ssl connector to access the web console via https.
Now I am trying to configure a webconsole access redirect from HTTP to HTTPS but I am really struggling with it.

In have found this guideline for "How to have Jetty redirect https to https" in this forum site: https://serverfault.com/questions/367660/how-to-have-jetty-redirect-http-to-https

I have problems to follow both steps since:

Step 1: Configure the web.xml file --> I don't know which of the following is the correct one:

- *apache-activemq-5.7.0/webapps/fileserver/WEB-INF/web.xml*
- *apache-activemq-5.7.0/webapps/admin/WEB-INF/web.xml*

Step 2: The instruction looks very different from the jetty.xml file of ActiveMQ where different connectors are used:

```xml
<property name="connectors">
    <list>
        <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <property name="port" value="8161" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
            <property name="port" value="8162" />
            <property name="keystore" value="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" />
            <property name="password" value="password" />
        </bean>
    </list>
</property>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Why not just remove the non-HTTPS connector or replace it with the HTTPS one? Then you wouldn't need a redirect.

Comment: Would it also work if a user is trying to open the webconsole via HTTP that this will change automatically to HTTPS and the webconsole still opens? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think so. The user will need to specify "https://". Of course, this is no different from needing the hostname and port. It's just part of the URL after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *admin* web app is the one you want to modify. The *fileserver* web app is for uploading files and it was removed in 5.14.0 via [AMQ-6276](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6276) due to security issues (e.g. [CVE-2016-3088](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2016-3088)).

I strongly encourage you to upgrade to the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/).